# llvm basic block predecessors llvm pred_iterator out of range

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm

I'm trying to iterator over the predecessors of a basic block and I'm getting using the following code:

```
for (::llvm::PredIterator PI = pred_begin(post_block); PI != pred_end(post_block); PI++)
{
    ::llvm::BasicBlock *pred = *PI;
    if (pred != exec_block)
    { ...
```

In the line with the if statement, I'm getting the following error:

```
In instantiation of ‘llvm::PredIterator<Ptr, USE_iterator>::reference llvm::PredIterator<Ptr, USE_iterator>::operator*() const [with Ptr = llvm::BasicBlock; USE_iterator = llvm::Value::use_iterator_impl<llvm::Use>; llvm::PredIterator<Ptr, USE_iterator>::reference = llvm::BasicBlock*]’:LLVMTC.cpp:1489:31:  
required from here /usr/local/include/llvm/Support/CFG.h:56:5: error: ‘const class llvm::Value::use_iterator_impl<llvm::Use>’ has no member named ‘atEnd’
 assert(!It.atEnd() && "pred_iterator out of range!");
```

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this problem? I'm basing my code off of: http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterating-over-predecessors-successors-of-blocks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First it's important to address the difference between your approach and the one in the example you're referencing.

In the example, they're define an instance of the `pred_iterator` type, rather than the `PredIterator` class you've used, which is defined as

```
typedef PredIterator<BasicBlock, Value::user_iterator> pred_iterator
```

and then using the calling `pred_begin` which returns an instance of `pred_iterator(BB)` where `BB` is the basic block you pass.

In your case, you're creating an instance of the `PredIterator` class and assigning it to the `BB` pointer, then attempting to dereference upon which it hits this assert:

```
inline reference operator*() const {
    assert(!It.atEnd() && "pred_iterator out of range!");
    return cast<TerminatorInst>(*It)->getParent();
}
```

As an initial solution it might be helpful to try and completely mimic the method used by the example, and then if you still need to use your method, try and diagnose the problem by observing how the typing for `PredIterator` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking though the svn history, Since LLVM 3.5, CFG.h has been moved from include/llvm/Support to include/llvm/IR. So you may want to use the following

```
#include "llvm/IR/CFG.h"
```

instead of

```
#include "llvm/Support/CFG.h"
```